# Five-component field

Tags: interactions, poincare-symmetry

Recently I was reading about 5-component field $(\varphi , \psi_{\mu})$, for which
$$
\hat {p}^{\mu} \varphi = mc\psi^{\mu}, \quad \hat {p}_{\mu}\psi^{\mu} = mc\varphi .
$$
This field refers to the spin-zero representation of the Lorentz group and obeys the Klein-Gordon massive equation (so it reproduces Poincare group irreducible representations).

What physical system is described by it?

Answer (score 1):

It might help if you provided context or references for your issue. As it stands, for non vanishing *m*, which is necessary if you are talking about spin and not helicity, the first equation is a *definition* of the auxiliary field function 
$$
\psi^\mu \equiv \frac{\hat{p}^\mu}{mc} ~\phi
$$
which makes the second equation the K-G equation for *φ*. I'm not sure what physical system you are seeking... Any physical system involving a spineless field is also likely to involve its gradient. The "5-array" you wrote is, of course, not a Lorentz vector.